# No file transfer window?

Tags: pantheon-files, files, usb

New to the forum and to elementary OS, trying it out and enjoying it very much for the moment, thanks to the devs!
I'm transferring a big folder from an external hard disk to the pc and I find it quite strange not to have a files transfer window popping up and showing me the transfer speed, the amount of time elapsed and so on.
Is it a deliberate decision not to have this window or is it just my fresh installation who's somehow missing it? Or is it an optional feature maybe?
Cheers,
Edoardo

Answer (score 0):

You should see a progress bar in the icon in the dock? There are some known bugs in the progress window at the moment e.g. see https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1275 and https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/1050.
I find that after some file transfers, the operation is  not properly cleaned up (e.g. the progress bar in the plank icon may continue to show) which may affect subsequent operations.  Hopefully it will be fixed in the not too distant future.

Comment: Hi Jeremy and thanks for your answer.I see it's a known issue then. I experience the exact same problems as those described in your first link. I do see a progress bar in the dock icon (actually the only proof that the transfer is ongoing), but that too eventually gets stuck in strange ways. Hope it gets fixed soon!